# yii pagination with searching not working

Tags: php, yii

I am implementing pagination (yii1) in my list page with search items: when I search something the pagination total item 5 (I mean link like 1 2 3 4 5) and the search's fine.

When I click a second page in pagination link, the total items increased to 12(i mean link like 1 2 3 4 5 ...10 11 12).

My query is working fine with like operator. I don't know where it's
getting changed..

This is in my controller

```
 if((isset($_POST['searchtext'])) && (!empty($_POST['searchtext']))){

       $sql ="select * from table1 where name LIKE '\'%'.$_POST['searchtext'].'%\'" ; 

       $sql_count = "select count(*) from table1 LIKE '\'%'.$_POST['searchtext'].'%\'" ;

       $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar();


   }else{

          $sql = "select * from table1";
          $sql_count = "select * from table1";
         $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar();
  }
   $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                'sort'=>array(
                 'attributes'=>array(
                 'id','userid','user_email',
                                    ),
                            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>9,
            ),
    ));
         $this->render('listallview',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,


    ));
```

And my view

```
        <ul class="list ">
          <?php

          $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_view',

            ));

          ?>
       </ul>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the pagination feature, you must configure the **totalItemCount** property to be the **total number** of rows (without pagination).

Try in your controller:

```
if((isset($_POST['searchtext'])) && (!empty($_POST['searchtext']))){

   $sql ="select * from table1 where name LIKE '\'%'.$_POST['searchtext'].'%\'" ; 

   //$sql_count = "select count(*) from table1 LIKE '\'%'.$_POST['searchtext'].'%\'" ;

   //$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar();


   }else{

      $sql = "select * from table1";
     //$sql_count = "select * from table1";
     //$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar();
     }

     $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1')->queryScalar();

     $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
            'totalItemCount'=>$count,
            'sort'=>array(
             'attributes'=>array(
             'id','userid','user_email',
                                ),
                        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>9,
        ),
));
     $this->render('listallview',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,


));
```